# Ether balance not showing on contract

Tags: erc-20

I have transferred ether to my contract but contract balance showing 0 and contract Creator balance increased . So I want to show that ether to my contract .

Please Help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the transaction id for the transaction that transferred the ether?

Comment: you can check transaction here https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xff4686f3846a8fa44fe72a940dab61d011b0197b893130fc267424ebd46a108d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the source code of this contract, but it looks like it forwarded the Ether to the creator. Here's the point in the execution where it did this. This is almost certainly something that was specifically added to the source code of the contract.

[image: Debugging in Remix Debugger]